# python requests- delete request

Tags: python, python-requests, httpresponse, http-delete

I'm trying to make a delete request using the python request library but I'm getting `response.ok = false` and error code `403`.
what I'm doing:

```
self.session = requests.Session()
...
response = self.session.delete(needed_url)
```

i'll appreciate some help. thanks!

Comment: You probably don't have access to delete the specified resource.

Comment: Are you providing credentials anywhere? 403 is a "Forbidden" error message.